# How to compare hdfs file with unix file?

Tags: python, linux, shell, hadoop, hdfs

I want to compare hdfs file with unix file.I know the one way using cat command we can compare files because of cat command also provided by Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS).

Let's take one example :

```
# hdfs dfs -ls -R /demo

-rw-r--r--   3 root hdfs     129617 2014-10-17 12:22 /demo/abc.log

#ls /tmp
xyz.log
```

Here i want to compare `abc.log` to `xyz.log`. Any better approach??

Answer (score 2):

You could probably use shell redirection + diff.

```
diff <(hdfs dfs -cat /demo/abc.log) <(cat /tmp/xyz.log)
```

Comment: Main reason behind not using cat command is that when i'm running cat or any command on hdfs then i'm getting some error or warning kind of thing then getting file content or expected output on console

Comment: I suppose you can do a couple of other things in that case.

You can redirect the stderr from hdfs command to /dev/null.

You can address the cause of the warnings when running hdfs.

Or you can use a hadoop library do line-by-line reads/comparison.

Any of the three 'should' work.  :)

Comment: Firstly thanks for reply.
Redirect stderr to /dev/null is not working in my case and also case about line by line read through hadoop library for this i need to write separate java program for it which i don't want.
Basically i'm writing python script for comparing this two files.